# Set DropDownList text and value c#

Tags: development, visual-web-part, dropdown

I am currently trying too develop a visual webpart for an on premise SharePoint environment. The webpart contains a dropdown which I need to set the text and value so that I can use this later as part of some CAML query.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
using (SPWeb web = new SPSite(siteurl).OpenWeb(weburl))
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("MyList");
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy>";
            SPListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);

            foreach (SPListItem item in collection)
            {
                MyDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem { item.Title, item.ID.ToString() });

            }

        }
```

I have tried a few different ways of getting this to work however I am getting an error message saying:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem)' has some invalid arguments

Any help on how I can achieve this or what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
using (SPWeb web = new SPSite(siteurl).OpenWeb(weburl))
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("MyList");
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy>";
        SPListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);

        MyDropdown.Datasource = collection;
        MyDropdown.DataTextField = "Title";
        MyDropdown.DataValueField = "ID";
        MyDropdown.DataBind();

    }
```